# Is EAGLE version 5 still around?

Tags: eaglecad

I am wondering if anyone still has the EAGLE installation file for version 5. For my purposes, version 5 works better than version 6 and I have deleted the old file.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but would you mind explaining what those purposes are? That is, why you must have version *five*? ...or why version *six* is worse? Thanks!

Comment: I also think v6 is better than v7, at least I did not like the new toolbar icons.

Answer (score 6):

If you go to the Cadsoft FTP site you can find them. Here's a link that will work open up the appropriate directory in a browser:

ftp://ftp.cadsoft.de/eagle/program/